# Creating a drop down menu with DIctionary Item

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have the following in my View:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Search, new SelectList(Model.SearchOptions))
```

In my Search Object I have:

```
    public List<string> Search { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> SearchOptions { get; set; }

    public SearchModel GetDropDownOptions(SearchModel model)
    {
        model.SearchOptions = HelperModel.GetRefValues(db, Constants.SEARCH, false);

        return model;
    }
```

With it calling:

```
public static Dictionary<String, String> GetRefValues(DBEntities db, string refType, bool addEmpty)
    {

        Dictionary<String, String> res = (from c in db.References
                                          where c.Type == refType
                                          select c).ToDictionary(c => c.Key.ToString(),
                                                                 c => c.Value.ToString());

        if (addEmpty)
            res.Add("", "");

        return res;
    }
```

I however get an error stating: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you initializing the db (DbEntities) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should validate the parameters of all public methods. So your method:

```
GetRefValues(DBEntities db, string refType, bool addEmpty)
```

should include a check to see if `db` is null and if `refType` is null. If you do that you'll be able to see which of those two are null and then you can fix your code accordingly by tracing back to see where they are initialized (or not, as the case may be.)